Checkboxes in XSLT: Not Allowed In Restricted Namespaces
I am using xslt to read an xml file and then display it in Microsoft Word. I want to implement checkboxes in my XSLT-files, but it doesn't work.
Currently it looks like this - now updated with full code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>

<xslt:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xslt="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml"
    xmlns:wx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint"
    xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"
    xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
    xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="w14">
    <xslt:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xslt:template match="/">   
        <w:wordDocument xml:space="preserve">
            <w:docPr>
                <w:view w:val="print"/>
                <w:zoom w:percent="130"/>
                <w:hideSpellingErrors w:val="on" />
                <w:hideGrammaticalErrors w:val="on" />
                <w:validateAgainstSchema w:val="off"/>
                <w:saveInvalidXML w:val="off"/>
                <w:ignoreMixedContent w:val="off"/>
                <w:doNotUnderlineInvalidXML w:val="on" />
                <w:removeWordSchemaOnSave w:val="on" />
                <w:useXSLTWhenSaving w:val="on" />
                <w:saveThroughXSLT w:val="on" />
                <w:showXMLTags w:val="off" />
                <w:alwaysShowPlaceholderText w:val="off"/>
                <w:attachedTemplate w:val="Normal.dotm"/>
            </w:docPr>
            <w:body>
                <w:sectPr>
                    <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838" w:code="9"/>
                    <w:pgMar w:top="567" w:right="1418" w:bottom="1134" w:left="1418" w:header="709" w:footer="709" w:gutter="0"/>
                </w:sectPr>
                <w:p/>
                <w:p>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>This is a checkbox:</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
                <w:p/>
                <w:p/>
                <w:p>
                    <w:sdt>
                        <w:sdtPr>
                            <w14:checkbox>
                                <w14:checked w14:val="0"/>
                                <w14:checkedState w14:val="2612" w14:font="MS Gothic"/>
                                <w14:uncheckedState w14:val="2610" w14:font="MS Gothic"/>
                            </w14:checkbox>
                        </w:sdtPr>
                        <w:sdtEndPr/>
                        <w:sdtContent>
                            <w:r>
                                <w:rPr>
                                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="MS Gothic" w:eastAsia="MS Gothic" w:hAnsi="MS Gothic" w:hint="eastAsia"/>
                                </w:rPr>
                                <w:t>☐</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                        </w:sdtContent>
                    </w:sdt>
                </w:p>
            </w:body>
        </w:wordDocument>
    </xslt:template> 
</xslt:stylesheet>

...Because this is pretty much what I got when I exported the docx-file to xml.
However when I try to use this, I get an error '6102', which states (roughly translated):
"Elements and attributes are not allowed in restricted namespaces."
The error comes from Microsoft Word (MSXML-processor).
I don't know what to do...
Thanks!

Please provide a [mcve].

Which software gives that error, which XSLT processor do you use?

Thank you. I edited my answer to give a minimal reproducible example and I added details about the XSLT processor.

No. A [mcve] includes an input and the expected result. --  I am guessing (!) that you are producing a Word 2003 XML document and you are trying to inject a checkbox using a Word 2010 schema. You should check the  Word 2003 XML documentation to see how a checkbox element should look like (assuming the format supports such feature at all).

You can select MSXML 6 as the XSLT processor at https://xsltfiddle-beta.liberty-development.net/, it doesn't give any error for your XSLT code. So it must be Word not being able to process the XSLT result, as you might not have produced the right XML for Word.

Thank you. I will read into everything everyone here said and come back to my issue asap.
